# Сортировка колонок таблицы

Tags: java, сортировка

Имеется таблица с несколькими столбцами, которая заполняется из базы данных (для упрощения привожу выбор данных для 1 столбца).

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT top 10 NDOK FROM AAAA.dbo.KKKK"); 
    ResultSet result =  ps.executeQuery();
    List<Customer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while(result.next()){
        Customer cust = new Customer();
                    cust.setNDOK(result.getString("NDOK"));

        list.add(cust);
    }
     con.close();   
    return list;
```

Что требуется - требуется подключить сортировку, которая будет работать по клику на заголовок таблицы (просто онклик, тут все понятно). Нашел пример сортировки, но он работает с конкретными данными, а не взятыми откуда-то -

```
public class TableData implements Serializable {
private SortFilterModel<Name> filterModel;
private static final Name[] names = {
  new Name("Anna", "Keeney"),
  new Name("John", "Wilson"),
  new Name("Mariko", "Randor"),
};
public TableData() {
  filterModel = new SortFilterModel<Name>(new ArrayDataModel<Name>(names));
}
public DataModel<Name> getNames() {
  return filterModel;
}
public String sortByFirst() {
  filterModel.sortBy(new Comparator<Name>() {
     public int compare(Name n1, Name n2) {
        return n1.getFirst().compareTo(n2.getFirst());
     }  
  });
  return null;
}
public String sortByLast() {
  filterModel.sortBy(new Comparator<Name>() {
     public int compare(Name n1, Name n2) {
        return n1.getLast().compareTo(n2.getLast());
     }  
  });
  return null;
}
}
```

В файле SortFilterModel тут лежит вроде как сам алгоритм сортировки, а в файле Name - геттеры-сеттеры аналогично как у меня в Customer.

Comment: На самом деле не понял в чем вопрос. Сортировка давно реализована в библиотеках различных, в т.ч. и стандартной, нужно лишь вызывать нужный метод с нужным компаратором. В чем конкретно загвоздка? Покажите свой "онклик", в нем и нужно сортировку делать я так понимаю.

Comment: Попробую точнее... У меня есть таблица в базе данных. Я получаю к ней доступ, и запрошенными данными из нее заполняю таблицу в xhtml файле. У меня есть пример (второй код), где при клике на заголовок столбца производится сортировка. Я хочу как то добавить такую же сортировку в свою программу.

Comment: Неясно как вы заполняете таблицу в xhtml файле, что у вас реализовано вообще, понимаете ли вы как вызывать обработчик для заголовка стоблца... По примеру кода который вы нашли также ничего нельзя понять, это просто класс, что он, куда и при каких условиях возвращает - непонятно. Сортировать данные тоже по-разному можно, можно доставать из базы отсортированные и просто выводить, а можно список готовый сортировать, опять же все зависит от контекста. У вас же в вопросе два огрызка кода, которые к сути проблемы мало относятся. Переформулируйте пожалуйста.

Comment: Отсортированные из базы - это понятно, просто немного дополняется SQL запрос. Но это не подходит, нужно чтобы сортировалась уже полученная из базы таблица, которая в аррейлист складывается. Второй код как раз это и дает - берет аррейлист, берет файл с сортировщиком и выполняет.

Answer (score 1):

java 8 - лямбда

```
Comparator.comparing(p->p.firstName);
Comparator.comparing(p->p.lastName);
```

< java 8

```
Comparator.comparing(Customer::getFirstName)
Comparator.comparing(Customer::lastName)
```